# Why should i use ViewModel suffix instead of VM?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This maybe a stupid question but ...

I see that the standard convention is to use the "ViewModel" suffix.

Could I use the VM suffix?

Why such a long suffix?

Comment: You can use VM, but what if someone else wanna to modify code later, so naming conventions are required.

Comment: You can use any names for models. It's a standard practice to use `ViewModel` suffix. Is it that hard to type additional 7 symbols?

Answer (score 4):

Just like all naming conventions, it's not that you *can't* use a different name, it's just recommended to stick to the naming rules for good practice and being kind to other developers if they ever need to revisit your code.

If this is a personal project, do whatever you want, just make sure you'll be able to figure it out later :)

Answer (score 4):

Personally i never use a suffix, that is almost as bad as using str and int prefixes.

Add your viewmodels to a ViewModel folder so they are separate from the models, this will change their namespace and leave their intention clear.

i would drop the suffix altogether and follow this practice instead.

Comment: I've done a half-way step to this, and have my Models folder with folders for each Controller and name each model after the action they represent, but suffixed with Model Models\Home\IndexModel.cs